# forcing the rule of having one record per combination in SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, relational-database

i have a table in sql that uses the [adjacency model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) to create child/parent relationship. here is the exact schema:

```
id int primary key identity(1,1)
name nvarchar(max)
parent int
```

now i want to have exactly one name with the same parent. another word for parent 1 there should only be one name. if that name wants to show up in another record, it must have a different parent. how can i do this in t-sql?

Comment: You'll have to write a trigger. I'll see if I have time later to elaborate.

Comment: Just in case, start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: I would avoid triggers. You can use a check constraint... or as stated below unique index.

Comment: It would be nice if you defined what you meant by parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for unique constraints.  This will allow you to define column combinations for which the data must be unique across the table, but are not part of the primary key.

Are you using SQL Server?  If so, these two articles should help:

Overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx

Creating/modifying: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177420.aspx

**Edit to provide example**

```
ALTER TABLE [YourTable]
ADD CONSTRAINT [YourConstraint] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([name], [parent])
```

Comment: those links only show how to create the unique constraint on one column. how can i create a combined constraint?

Comment: Yes, just separate with commas, see updated answer.  You can also do it in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique index on (parent, name).

Comment: how can i create an unique constraint on two columns? i've heard that this is possible but i've never seen an example.